# How can I indent using an increasing number of spaces before each line?

Tags: python-3.x, string

Function to indent using an increasing number of spaces before each line.

```python
str1 = ['Germany','France','Australia','England','Switzerland']
str2 = '\n'
for i in str1:
    print(str2.join(str1))
```

Output should be:

```
Germany
  France
    Australia
      England
        Switzerland
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will be simple enough:

```
for i, s in enumerate(str1):
    print(" " * 2 * i + s)
```